SQL Server database connectivity for read data
I have a question regarding database connectivity. I'm attempting to connect my chatbot to a local SQL Server database using "SQL Database Chain" but struggling to establish a successful connection. Despite trying various connection string formats, I haven't had any luck. Could someone guide me on correctly formatting the connection string for this purpose?
I'm using the below connection string for my .NET projects. This is working fine.
Server=BUDDHIKA\\MSSQLSERVER04; Initial Catalog=chatApp; persist security info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;

Tried below connection strings below with FlowiseAI but had no luck.
mssql+pyodbc://BUDDHIKA\MSSQLSERVER04/ChatApp?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&trusted_connection=yes

mssql+pyodbc://tcp:BUDDHIKA\\MSSQLSERVER04/ChatApp?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server&trusted_connection=yes;port=49767

Any help would be greatly appreciated!


It would help if you Edited your question to include the full and complete error message(s) that you are receiving. As text, not screen shots.

Are you running Flowise in a Docker container or have you used npm to install it directly on your computer? If it's in a Docker container then you'll need to use SQL Login authentication (with a username and password that's not for a Windows account) connecting to host.docker.internal\MSSQLSERVER04.

Hi @AlwaysLearning Thank you for the reply.
I am using direct npm install.

Did you read https://docs.flowiseai.com/configuration/databases ? it kind of fails to mention mssql
